# How to copy data between postgres schemas if there are objects?

Tags: postgresql, backup, insert, sequence, cast

I removed shop from database, that should not be removed. Fortunately I had backup and reverted this backup to schema `public_backup`.

Now I am trying to restore only this shop. I can't override my current data by backup because there are new data.

I am executing command:

```
INSERT INTO public.shop ( SELECT * FROM public_backup.shop WHERE id = 'id_to_backup' ) ;
```

but I am receiving error:

```
[42804] ERROR: column "invoice_id_reseting_type" is of type invoice_reseting_type but expression is of type public_backup.invoice_reseting_type
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

type `invoice_reseting_type` is mentioned in `object types`.

I created cast:

```
CREATE CAST (public_backup.invoice_reseting_type AS public.invoice_reseting_type) WITH INOUT;
```

but it does not helped.

Can I skip this checking or cast it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the column to `text` and then to the desired type:

```
CAST (
   CAST (invoice_id_reseting_type AS text)
   AS invoice_reseting_type
)
```

You have to list the columns instead of using `*` for that.

Comment: I am doing it manually now, like you suggested, but I am disappointed that there is not less verbose method.

Comment: There is: `invoice_id_reseting_type::text::invoice_reseting_type`, if you don't mind proprietary syntax.